# Casting an Interface to an Object in C#

Tags: casting

I have a few objects that contain a lot of varying methods:

```
   public class Dog: AnimalDescription, IAnimal
   public class Cat: AnimalDescription, IAnimal
```

I want to put a `list` of Dogs and Cats into a combined list. From there I want to create a slideshow and play each item respectively. So I've made an interface:

```
   public Interface IAnimal
       public playAnimal()
```

I have a `catItem` and `dogItem` that extends this interface.

My problem lies here, I can't combine the list. Everytime I do it says I'm not casting it correctly:

I want to add it to an AnimalInterface list and go through each catItem or dogItem method (playAnimal) depending on the class Type. I have a class that creates a slideshow for the animals:
But the following does not work:

```
   public class AnimalSlideshow

   IEnumerable<IAnimal> AnimalItemList;


   setUpSlideshow(list<Dogs> newDogData){
      var dogList = newDogData.Where(dog => anyDog.anySpecies().toList());

      //The dogList is a type List<Dog>.

       AnimalItemList = dogList.Cast<IAnimal>();
   }
```

It says I can't cast a Dog to type IAnimal. I'm confused because I added the Interface to the Dog class. I just recently started learning C#. Is there something I'm understanding incorrectly?

Comment: `Cast` doesn't return a list.  It returns an `IEnumerable` try adding a `ToList` after that.

Comment: Neither dogs nor cats are `AnimalItem`. Shouldn't you be casting them to `IAnimal` ?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet that is a *list* of animals. What you typed will throw.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `AnimalItem` is the name of the OP's interface, unless you're trying to recommend a better name (which I agree with)

Comment: If `newDogs` is a list of `Dog`, then it _already_ is a list of `IAnimal`.  If you instantiate a `List<IAnimal>` you can add _anything_ that implements `IAnimal` (Cat or Dog).

Comment: @juharr the interface is *IAnimal*, not *AnimalItem*. The Dog and Cat classes implement `IAnimal`, not `AnimalItem`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry my bad, it was a typo. They are currently being cast to IAnimal

Comment: @lost9123193 then what's the problem? And where did `AnimalItemList ` come from??  Please post the *actual, complete* code. Don't throw surprises like this

Comment: In any case, `Cast<IAnimal>()` will return an `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`. You can convert it to a `List<IAnimal>` with `.ToList()`.

Comment: Going with Panagiotis Kanavos here--the problem could likely be related to whatever `AnimalItemList` is.  Did you mean to put `var` in front of that, or have you declared it as something specific already?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine both cats and dogs in a list of animals, you should use the Enumerable.Concat operator.

You'll have to cast the first list to an `IEnumerable<IAnimal>` first:

```
interface IAnimal{}

public class Cat:IAnimal{}

public class Dog:IAnimal{}

var cats=new List<Cat> {
   new Cat(),
   new Cat()
};
var dogs=new List<Dog> {
   new Dog(),
   new Dog()
};

var animals = cats.Cast<IAnimal>()
                  .Concat(dogs)
                  .ToList();

Debug.Assert(animals.Count == 4);
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Would a dictionary dog list prevent the casting? I'm reading the error message and it's saying my data is a System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
      dogs.Add(new Dog());
      dogs.Add(new Dog());
      dogs.Add(new Dog());

      var x = dogs.Where(dog => true).ToList();
      var y = x.Cast<IAnimal>();
      var z = y.ToList();

    }
  }
  public class Dog :  IAnimal { }
  public class Cat :  IAnimal { }
  public interface IAnimal { }
```

in this example,
`x` is of type `List<Dog>`
`y` is of type `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`
`z` is of type `List<IAnimal>`

Answer (score 0):

I think we'll need more code/more information as to what's going on in the background.  I've taken the code you've provided, tweaked it slightly to get it to compile, and then ran it in LinqPad and it works just fine (see below). I recognize that the Devil is in the details, though, so some of the assumptions I've made are likely different than what you have actually done.

```
void Main()
{
    AnimalSlideshow slides = new AnimalSlideshow();
    slides.setUpSlideshow(new List<Dog> { new Dog()});
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    void playAnimal();
}

public class AnimalDescription
{ }
public class Dog : AnimalDescription, IAnimal
{
    public void playAnimal() { }
    public bool anySpecies() {return true;}
}
public class Cat : AnimalDescription, IAnimal
{
    public void playAnimal() {}
}

public class AnimalSlideshow
{
    IEnumerable<IAnimal> AnimalItemList;

    public void setUpSlideshow(List<Dog> newDogData)
    {
        var dogList = newDogData.Where(dog => dog.anySpecies()).ToList();

        //The dogList is a type List<Dog>.

        AnimalItemList = dogList.Cast<IAnimal>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. I'm still getting an error "unable to cast object Dog to IAnimal). Would a dictionary dog list prevent the casting? I'm reading the error message and it's saying my data is a System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Comment: I wouldn't think so--Dictionary and List are both IEnumerable, so that shouldn't change anything.  As noted, showing more of your code could be helpful to discover what part is wrong.

Comment: Take a good look at your line:  `var dogList = newDogData.Where(dog => anyDog.anySpecies().toList());` vs. my line `var dogList = newDogData.Where(dog => dog.anySpecies()).ToList();`  I had to change a few important details to get it to compile.  For example, where did `anyDog` come from?  And also note that the closing parenthesis for the `Where` moved inward.  I bet your problem has to do with this line.